# left quotation mark ` is not printing as expected

Tags: polyglossia, quotation

I am typesetting a multi language document with XeLaTeX. but when i use ` this symbol (it is the key below escape and under ~) to produce left quote it come as a slopped instead of curved. here is the image.
[image: this is how quote is getting printed]
i dont know what happens there. i am attaching the link of the example in overleaf. https://www.overleaf.com/read/ybcqvksfrytc

Comment: it is better to add a small complete example as a code block in the question rather than rely on external links

Comment: it was a large document, let me try to reproduce in very minimal code and in single file. i will update asap.

Comment: Looks like you are maybe using an apostrophe on the right, instead of a closing quote?

Comment: nope. i am using ' key. which is left to Enter key

Comment: @Mujeebcpy I put a small example in my answer, hopefully it will apply to your real case as well

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

with a cut down version of your Overleaf document:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}

\newfontfamily\englishfont[Script=Latin]{Gentium}[
Script=Latin,
UprightFont=Arial,
BoldFont=Arial,
ItalicFont=Arial,
Ligatures=TeX % or Mapping=tex-text
]

\begin{document}

\englishfont `zzz'

\end{document}
```

without the Mapping or (better, Ligatures) option, you get

[image]

Comment: Thank you. this works!! 
i would like to know how the solution works? what is really changing here? any helpful link is enough. i didn't get any results from searching. is this related to specific font?

Comment: @Mujeebcpy you need the tex ligatures enabled so the ascii quotes turn into proper quotes and `---` turns into an emdash etc. It turns out that fontspec only does this by default for fonts set with `\setmainfont`   and other top level commands, it does not do it for `\newfontfamily` so you need to add it.